# Azure Data Factory throwing "Invoking Azure function failed with HttpStatusCode - InternalServerError."

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-data-factory

I am getting this error while trying to invoke azure function through the data factory. Snap of the error is attached.

I then again tried with the same parameters, and the next instance of execution just worked fine.

I just wanted to know if this problem is from azure server side or due to from my code.
Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Was your function already up and running when the first call was made? If your second call was working, then It is possible that you'd get this error if you just started the app service and attempted to execute the pipeline. The app service takes 10-20s to start up but this is not obvious from your question. I would say that you should check the application insights connected to your app to see what was the error in the logs for that particular call.

Comment: @AnupamChand, The role of ADF in my solution is to convert zipped image to unzipped one and then to dumped that unzipped image to Azure file share which will be required for further processing. The time when I got this error is for the single image when I done the processing of 15000 images, means out of 15000 executions 1 got failed. And for the information this image is not the first one or the last, it is the intermediate one out of 15000. Thanks

Comment: Ok thanks, in that case the reason for the error will be definitely in the application insights logs. It looks like this error is from the Azure function. Have a look at this documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/asp-net-exceptions

Comment: @AnupamChand.Thanks for the suggestion, will go through this.

Answer (score 0):

> Call to provided Azure function 'OnCopySuccess' failed with
> status-'InternalServerError' and message - 'Invoking Azure function
> failed with HttpStatusCode - InternalServerError.

Has nothing to do with Azure DataFactory, it fails because of the Azure Functions, HAs from the error you will not be able to detect any issues so, you may examine the output of your azure function app using logs in kudu, in addition to the monitor of the azure function.

In addition, kudu log files are more timely than the Azure function's monitor.
Simply navigate to this website's address.
Click on the URL `https://yourfunctionappname.scm.azurewebsites.net/DebugConsole`

Go To: `LogFiles\Application\Functions\Function\yourtriggername`

The log files can then be found. The log file in Kudu is real-time, whereas the monitor takes a while to show (typically 5 minutes).

HTTP Function is supposed to actually return an HTTP result, See the [Original Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52198587/getting-internal-server-error-when-i-run-my-azure-function-in-the-portal) - So you might check your Azure Function Code.

Comment: I had no log files here and it still gives me this error without our team changing anything in our environments.